# Reading printer data

Tags: c#

I've been presented with a task where I'm unfamiliar with concepts.

Task - read printer data stream from a POS system.

Terms mentioned
ESC/P

I have to read values coming from a POS system. My first question is how can you determine the start and end of a print job?

I guess I'm looking for control characters of a printer maybe?

Also, is there a way to simulate this without interrupting the POS?

Anyone know good examples or references they are familiar with themselves?

Comment: Contact the POS system manufacturer to obtain their reference manuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about [Printdocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx)
It has BeginPrint, and EndPrint event. You can subscribe to them with an eventhandler.

I'm not familiar with POS system, but i hope it's helpful for your first question.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to know how is the POS system connected to your computer. It could be LPT port, COM port, or USB port. Then you can figure out how to read the data.

But under Windows, LPT may be held by printer spooler. You may need to disable spooler before talking to LPT1 directly.

Normally, it's easier to do these kind of stuff using C++, directly using Win32 API.